# Adjusting a CSS Ribbon on Thumbnails in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a css ribbon on this panel of picture. But the ribbon keeps on appearing on the upper right side of the screen.
Here is my HTML Code

```
<li class="span4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
```

```
</div>
```

```
                  <img src="img/placeholder-360x200.jpg" alt="product name">
                  <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Product name</h3>
                    <p>
                      Few attractive words about your product.Few attractive words about your product.
                      Few attractive words about your product.Few attractive words about your product.
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="widget-footer">
                    <p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy now</a>&nbsp;
                      <a href="product.html" class="btn">Read more</a>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

The CSS code can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UBfCE/2/).

And a screenshot of what I'm trying to build
[image: Trying to put a ribbon on each image thumbnail]

Comment: Where are you trying to put the ribbon.. on each picture, or to the right of all 3?

Comment: @Skelly I was trying to put the ribbon to the right of all 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/UBfCE/68/

```
   .ribbon-wrapper{
    margin:0 0 0 212px;
    position:absolute;
    }
```

Comment: thank you, btw what part of the css would I change if I wanted the ribbon to appear on all three Pictures.